# SwiftUI macOS usable system icons

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, icons

I have the following versions:

```
macOs: 10.15.4
Xcode: 11.7
```

There is a way to use system icons or icons designed to be used for macOS apps.

What should I use `Image` or `UIImage`?

Is there a list of all icons online?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/name?changes=latest_major ...  and definitely it is not `UIImage`, but `NSImage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/name?changes=latest_major ...  and definitely it is not `UIImage`, but `NSImage`.

```
var body: some View {
    Image(nsImage: NSImage(named: NSImage.computerName) ?? NSImage())
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
}
```

Comment: Any reason why the computer image would be blurry? (macOS 11)